# Google appengine datastore filter with OR like sql (golang)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a struct

```
type Test struct{
Name      string
Creation  time.Time
User      *datastore.Key
Membres   []*datastore.Key
}
```

I want equivalent of this sql query in datastore query

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE User=myOwnUser OR myOwnUser in(Membres)
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GQL provides many SQL-like features, but OR isn't one of them (see [GQL reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax)).  You could do two queries and a set intersection on the results.  Alternatively you could denormalize a bit and add a UserAndMembers property which contained both and then just use an IN query.